# Tree shaking using webpack and typescript

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular, webpack

I'm trying to reduce the weight of my angular 2 app.

I'm using typescript (1.8.10) and webpack (1.13) as moduler bundlers.

I have minified all my ts files.
I have enabled the gzip compression in my server and now I want to use the tree shaking , but I don't have found any loader or similar to use it in my project. I have found the rollup moduler bundler but I don't want to change my moduler bundler (I think that webpack is better for me).

Someone knows how to use the tree shaking with webpack?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi noor, If you are using ngix, you can check this link: https://easyengine.io/tutorials/nginx/enable-gzip/
If you have apache: https://www.giftofspeed.com/enable-gzip-compression/

Regards!

Answer (score 2):

Webpack 2 combined with TypeScript 2 supports tree-shaking with the UglifyJSPlugin webpack plugin out of the box. This is probably the easiest solution for your case.
There is a great blog on how it is done here:
http://blog.rangle.io/optimize-your-angular2-application-with-tree-shaking/

Comment: Yes, I've seen that TS 2 it has been delivered but webpack is still in 1.13 :( We should wait a little bit more, because otherwise I think it's a very bad idea to use webpack beta in production.